# Product zoom option is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, jquery

Product page zoom option is not working, i have using

1. js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js
2. css/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.css

My working website  **http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/**

Product page **http://machinetoolsemart.com/wim-ig-200-i-single-phase-without-arc-accessories.html**

Anybody know what is the problem is going on my website?

Comment: you have jquery  issue. you are using the jquery varailble but not defined int.add this in first line  `jQuery=$.noConflict();` `cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js` and make sure you added the jquery library..

Comment: I have an issue like hover image divided, could u guide how can i solve this error. My question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/194453/57334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some JavaScript errors on your Page, some libraries couldn't be loaded by the client.
You have to verify why the necessary JavaScript libraries are not being loaded. For CloudZoom is JQery a dependency, so look into the layout configuration of your theme, should be in
`app/design/frontend/default/theme697/layout/`
and search for "jquery".
There should be a definition of it.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked `Product page`, there's NO `http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js` is loaded, BTW it's added to `Homepage`. So make it available to `Product Page` also

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the jQuery library
Сloud-Zoom http://prntscr.com/arr6jl depends on jQuery

local.xml

example:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!---Default Pages-->
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```